# Not able to associate X-Labels to corresponding bars in a bar chart using d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have created a column bar chart as in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KXE7j/2/). But the problem is I am not able to associate X-axis labels to specific bars (directly under the bars). Can you help me ? My code is as below.

```
function drawColumnChart() {
    var dataArray_o, maxNum_f, canvas_o,  canvas_top;

    dataArray_o = [
        {name: "PS 1", value: "3000" },
        {name: "PS 2", value: "1000" },
        {name: "PS 3", value: "5000" },
        {name: "PS 4", value: "2000" }
    ];
    var values = [];
    var names = [];
    for (var index_i = 0; index_i < dataArray_o.length; index_i++) {
        values.push(dataArray_o[index_i].value);
        names.push(dataArray_o[index_i].name);
    }
    maxNum_f = Math.max.apply(null, values);


    var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40}
    var w = 500 - margin.left - margin.right, h = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var yScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, maxNum_f]).rangeRound([0, h]);
    var yScale1 = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, maxNum_f]).rangeRound([h, 0]);

    var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, w], 0)  ;

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale1).ticks(5).orient("left");
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale).orient("bottom").tickFormat(function(v){
        console.log(v);
        return v;   
    });

    canvas_top= d3.select("#ColumnChart").append("svg").attr("height", h + margin.top + margin.bottom).attr("width", w + margin.left + margin.right);
    canvas_o = canvas_top.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(50, 0)");
    var rects = canvas_o.selectAll("rect");


        var totalRect = h / 20 ; 
        var dArr = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < totalRect; i++) {
            dArr.push(i);
        }

        var bars2 =  rects.data(dArr).enter().append("rect").attr("height", function(d){
                return 20;
        }).attr("width", w).attr("x", function(d, i){
            return 0;
        }).attr("y", function(d, i){
            return i *20;
        }).
        attr("fill", function(d, i) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                return "grey";
            } else {
                return "white";
            }
        }).attr("opacity", "0.08");

    rects.data(dataArray_o).enter().append("rect").attr("class", "bar").attr("width", 15).attr("height", function(d) {
        return yScale(d.value);
    }).attr("x", function(d, i) {
        return i*30 + 5;
    }).
    attr("y", function(d, i) {
        return h - yScale(d.value);
    }).attr("fill", "#330066");

    canvas_top.selectAll("text").data(dataArray_o).enter().append("text").text(function(d) {
        return d.value;
   }).attr("text-anchor", "middle")
   .attr("x", function(d, i) {
        return i*30 + 10;
   })
   .attr("y", function(d) {
        return h - yScale(d.value);
   })
   .attr("font-family", "sans-serif") 
   .attr("font-size", "11px")
   .attr("fill", "white");
    xScale.domain(names);
    canvas_top.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(50, 5)").call(yAxis);
    canvas_top.append("g").
    attr("transform", "translate(50," + h  +")").
    call(xAxis);
}
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Have you seen [this tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/3/)?

Comment: Lars, Thank you so much. Though it didn't give me the direct answer, it gave the pointer to think through. Appreciate your help.